# Display the cells involved in the calculation of the current cell

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Can I configure LibreOffice Calc so that when I select a cell with a calculation like:

```
=C1 * C2
```

then those cells are "shown" (border change or background color change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice works that way without needing any configuring:

[image: highlight source cells]

To see this, click on `=C1 * C2` to place the cursor in the formula bar, or double-click on cell C3.

Comment: Is there a way to do this only when the cell is selected but not in edition mode?